# OpenTBS exceeding maximum execution time

Tags: php, opentbs

I've this massive array which, unfortunately, has to be processed by the OpenTBS class. I'd rather a smaller array and apparently so does OpenTBS as it is exceeding its maximum execution time. It can't be my query as I timed that at 2.3 seconds when I switched OpenTBS off and when I put it back on so it could be merged, it just took forever to end up with a PHP error message.

Should I increase the maximum execution time? Is it wise in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration of 2.3 second for the query suggests that you have a large volume of data. It is quite common to increase the maximum execution time for large data merging.

But you can also try to check for optimization in your template.

See the FAQ: [The merge is too slow](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#faq_slow).